# SQLAlchemy associating only one column with ID

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a value for ingredients, amount, and unit associated to a single ingredient_id. The individual columns get associated to a separate ingredient_id for some reason. Here is the output after trying to add it to the db.

| ingredient_id | ingredients | amount | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ingredient1 | Null | Null |
| 2 | Null | 1.0 | Null |
| 3 | Null | Null | Amount1 |

Here is the table setup

```
class recipeMaster(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipemaster'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    ingredients = db.relationship('Ingredients')

class Ingredients(db.Model):
    ingredient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipemaster.id'))
    ingredients = db.Column(db.String(50))
    amount = db.Column(db.Float)
    unit = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

And here is how I'm committing it to the db. I've tried to add a single column at a time but get the same result.

```
ingredientName = Ingredients(ingredients = getIngredient)
            amountName = Ingredients(amount = getAmount)
            unitName = Ingredients(unit = getUnit)
            db.session.add_all([ingredientName, amountName, unitName])
            db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried committing it like this and got the output I expected.

```
data = Ingredients(ingredients = getIngredient, amount = getAmount, unit = getUnit)
db.session.add(data)
db.session.commit()
```